# Access violation trying to play MP4 file with WindowsMediaPlayer ActiveX component with Delphi Sydney

Tags: delphi, mp4, windows-media-player

I try to make an app to play mp4 files.

I have import WindowsMediaPlayer ActiveX control as suggested at `https://blogs.embarcadero.com/add-windows-media-player-to-your-delphi-applications/` but when i execute the play command always i get the error message `access violation at xxxxx` where xxxxx is an address in `c:\WINDOWS\sysWOW64\D3D9.DLL`.

EDIT

The code is

```
    unit Uvideo;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.MPlayer, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.OleCtrls, WMPLib_TLB;

type
  TForm7 = class(TForm)
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    Splitter1: TSplitter;
    Button1: TButton;
    WindowsMediaPlayer1: TWindowsMediaPlayer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form7: TForm7;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL := 'file://H:\SYSTEMFOLDERS\videos\WinXVideos\L533.mp4';
    WindowsMediaPlayer1.controls.play; // the AV raises even without this statement
end;

end.
```

NEW EDIT

With the code above i can play mp3 but not mp4.

If i use ...

```
begin
WindowsMediaPlayer1.openPlayer('file://H:\SYSTEMFOLDERS\videos\WinXVideos\L533.mp4');
end
```

... it plays the mp4 file (but in a second media player context).

My Delphi is Win32 and i have import the component as win32.

What the problem is ?

Comment: You need to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your q.

Comment: The only code is 
```procedure TForm7.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL := 'file://H:\SYSTEMFOLDERS\videos\eisagvgh.mp4';
  WindowsMediaPlayer1.controls.play;
end;```

Comment: You did not initialize WindowsMediaPalyer1 variable.

Comment: WindowsMediaPalyer1 object created automatically by the program. Isn't initialized ?

Comment: @fpiette: Probably a component dropped on the form, so it is crated automatically before `OnCreate` is run.

Comment: @jim: Are you sure it is possible to call `Play` before the form is shown on-screen? Perhaps the form needs to be properly displayed first?

Comment: The same behavior when i call play from a button's onclick event.


    procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL := 'file://H:\SYSTEMFOLDERS\videos\WinXVideos\L533.mp4';
        WindowsMediaPlayer1.controls.play;
    end;

Comment: I just tried to install the Windows Media Player ActiveX control and was able to use this code snippet to play an MP4 video on my computer. No AV. I'm using Windows 7 (64-bit), Delphi 10.3, 32-bit app, Aero enabled.

Comment: I use win10/64 Delphi 10.4.1 32bit

Comment: Successful test with Win10/64, Delphi XE7 32 bit. Have you tested with other files/types? Have you tested playing same files/types with the player that comes with Win 10? Have you dl'ed some codecxpacxs (hope not)

Comment: The mp4 file plays right with windows player. I have installed VLC player, does it make sense ?
The app plays mp3 files but not mp4.

Comment: This code plays the mp4 file (but in a second media player context).
```procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
WindowsMediaPlayer1.openPlayer('file://H:\SYSTEMFOLDERS\videos\WinXVideos\L533.mp4');
end;```
but this code raises an AV just when setting the URL
```procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL := 'file://H:\SYSTEMFOLDERS\videos\WinXVideos\L533.mp4';
 //  WindowsMediaPlayer1.controls.play;
end;```